# InputTextarea with maximum rows and columns

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I need an inputfield for a text with maximum 25 chars/cols and 5 lines/rows.
Is it possible to set maximum rows and columns to a [PrimeFaces InputTextarea](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputTextarea.xhtml)?
Maybe with an extension like OmniFaces?

Comment: At your own link I saw in demo code `<p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="30" maxlength="10" ... />`. Didn't that work for you? At least with a calculated maxlength like 25*5.

Comment: No, that is not working.   
The "rows" are like an initial value. With a "maxlength" of 10 I would be able to insert a text of 10 rows with one letter.   
I need an inputfield with maximum 25 chars/cols and 5 lines/rows. No 6. line.

Comment: Ah ok, this way. This is not supported by HTML spec. You'll need to look in the JavaScript corner to automatically insert newlines and/or block typing and such. A feature request at PrimeFaces to add a new attribute like `fixedsize="true"` which auto-activates that JavaScript can also. OmniFaces isn't an UI library ;)